# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied build error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, build

I am trying to build a solution. However, one of the projects has build error. The error message is as follows:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied 
at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)    
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()   
Unexpected exception:   
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.ManagedCompiler.ExecuteTool(String pathToTool, String responseFileCommands, String commandLineCommands)
```

What is the cause of the build error and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Try cleaning your projects (remove .vs folders) and rebuild.

Comment: May I know what cause the downvoite of question? Maybe I can refine the question.

Comment: How can I find out which file is causing the Access is denied?

Comment: You can change the verbosity of the output in *Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run*. Maybe then you will see the causing file. (btw, I don't know the cause for the downvote, conterupvote...)